# SQL Server como agrupar registros por sequências quebradas

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Bom dia, caros!

Preciso criar um código para trazer registros desta maneira:

[registro de livros][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITiTb.jpg

Porém a tabela em que se encontram os registros, está assim:

[tabela de livros][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdiUy.jpg

O código desenvolvido até agora é esse:

```
SELECT
SCERTIFICADO.CODLIVRO, SCERTIFICADO.NUMREGISTRO
FROM SCERTIFICADO (NOLOCK)
WHERE
SCERTIFICADO.TIPO = 'D'
AND SCERTIFICADO.STATUS = 'E'
AND SCERTIFICADO.DTEMISSAO >= '2020-01-01'
AND SCERTIFICADO.DTEMISSAO <= '2022-12-01'
ORDER BY
SCERTIFICADO.CODLIVRO, SCERTIFICADO.NUMREGISTRO
```

---

Alguém teria alguma sugestão de como conseguir realizar esse agrupamento por registro, de sequências quebradas?

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Não publique imagens , publique como texto na pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Segue uma sugestão para testes onde é utilizada a função *Row_Number* para numerar as linhas e assim identificar as que estão em uma sequencia continua para fazer o agrupamento:

```
with CTE_RN as
(
    select 
        CODLIVRO, 
        NUMREGISTRO, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODLIVRO ORDER BY NUMREGISTRO) AS RN
    from Tabela
)

select
    CODLIVRO,
    MIN(NUMREGISTRO) AS DE,
    MAX(NUMREGISTRO) AS ATE
from CTE_RN
group by
    CODLIVRO,
    RN - NUMREGISTRO
order by
    CODLIVRO,
    DE
```